# Angular 12 How can i set eventlistner to dynamic SVG path's (circle,line) which is coming from backend?I ma

Tags: angular, svg, events, dynamic, binding

I am trying

var svgAsDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgAsString, 'text/html')

```
    for (var key in attributeMap) {

        if (svgAsDocument.getElementById(key) != null) {
            svgAsDocument.getElementById(key).setAttribute('visibility', attributeMap[key])
            svgAsDocument.getElementById(key).setAttribute('fill', '#006600')
            svgAsDocument.getElementById(key).addEventListener('click', (event)=>this.setTitle());
        }
    }
```

Attributes are setting properly but event binding are not.Please help me if anyone can?

Comment: can you expand this into an [mcve] please. We're missing svgAsString currently and attributeMap so we can't see what you're actually executing.

Comment: Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k59bzy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts   here i am able to set "fill" and "visibility" property but i can-not set click event on the element.